# SwiftUI: Singleton class not updating view

Tags: swift, xcode, class, swiftui, singleton

New to SwiftUI... I have the following simplified code. The intended functionality is to be able to navigate between `View1()` and `View2()`, using a singleton class to keep track of this navigation.

I suspect that maybe I needed to add `@Published` to my `show_view_2` variable, but I want to keep it in App Storage. Also, I understand this isn't the best way to switch between views, but I only am using this method because it's a minimally reproduced example.

Why isn't the below code working, and how can I make it work?

```
class Player {
    static var player = Player()
    @AppStorage("show_view_2") var show_view_2: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {  
    var body: some View {
        if(Player.player.show_view_2) {
            View2()
        } else {
            Text("Go to View2")
                .onTapGesture {
                    Player.player.show_view_2 = true
                }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Back to View1")
            .onTapGesture {
                Player.player.show_view_2 = false
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a singleton. You should be using `@StateObject` on an instance of `Player` instead. I don't see why you'd be looking for a singleton, unless you wanted the same object between multiple views. If so, just pass it down through view `init`s or through the environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SwiftUI to know to update, `Player` should be an `ObservableObject`. Also, it'll need to be accessed using a property wrapper (either `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`) on the `View`:

```
class Player : ObservableObject {
    static var player = Player()
    @AppStorage("show_view_2") var show_view_2: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var player = Player.player
    
    var body: some View {
        if player.show_view_2 {
            View2()
        } else {
            Text("Go to View2")
                .onTapGesture {
                    player.show_view_2 = true
                }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @StateObject private var player = Player.player
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Back to View1")
            .onTapGesture {
                player.show_view_2 = false
            }
    }
}
```

In general, I'd recommend *not* using a singleton and instead passing an instance of the object explicitly between views -- this will be more testable and flexible over time:

```
class Player : ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("show_view_2") var show_view_2: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var player = Player()
    
    var body: some View {
        if player.show_view_2 {
            View2(player: player)
        } else {
            Text("Go to View2")
                .onTapGesture {
                    player.show_view_2 = true
                }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @ObservedObject var player : Player
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Back to View1")
            .onTapGesture {
                player.show_view_2 = false
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the ContentView Player() instantiation be the same object/have the same attributes as the View2 Player()?

Comment: Yes, in both examples I gave.